# What does it mean to check behind?

Tags: poker, poker-texas-holdem

In poker terminology, there's something called "checking behind". What does this mean?

Comment: If you are interested in Poker please commit to the new [Poker SE Currently on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3425/poker?referrer=AGKNzHVrmSTgMMEpzVsZAg2)

Comment: I'm already commited there :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's when you 'check' (choose not to bet anything) after all players before you have checked.  Often with a good hand you'll want to do this to give your opponent(s) an opportunity to improve and be willing to bet.  With a weak hand you might want to do this if you suspect your opponent is slow-playing a good hand for the same reason.

Comment: With an un-beatable hand it is a good idea to check behind, and let someone catch up.  Otherwise, you want to make bets which make it a mistake for them to attempt to draw out - because more often than you want, they will draw out.

Comment: Mostly good advice for a normal situation in a cash game.  However, like nearly all advice on poker strategy, it depends.  There are other factors that affect this decision, so don't take this as a hard and fast rule.  This is why I said 'often' in the answer above.

Answer (score 3):

Checking behind is when you are last to act, and you check.

Comment: Is this identical to the other answer?  If you, it'd be better to vote it up instead of answering yourself.  If not, please expand upon the differences so that voters can make an informed choice.  Thanks!

Comment: The other answer says that it is checking behind when all players before you have checked.  If there is someone behind you still to act, that is not (what I know as) checking behind.

Comment: According to http://www.pokerstrategy.com/glossary/Check-Behind/, @ChrisMarasti-Georg is right - it's only a check-behind if you're last to act.

Comment: It is a real advantage to check (bet, or raise) "behind," (after everyone else has acted) which is why you can play weaker cards than usual on the "button," or "last" position.